# SATA DVD drive doesn't work

Tags: dvd, sata, jumper

I built a computer about 3 years ago and seldom needed the dvd drive to work but when I did it was a pain to get it running.

I have a SATA HDD and a SATA dvd drive which seemed to me to be part of the problem.  The dvd drive had jumper pins on the back and the only way I could get it working was to turn off the computer and change the jumper setting.

I don't fully understand jumper settings but I do know that this, more or less, worked.  The issue is now I'm building a computer for my sister and this build also has a SATA dvd drive but i don't want the same thing to happen.

Also, how do jumper settings work in case I need to set that for the master and slave hard drives in addition to the dvd drive?

Comment: let me clarify, i had to change the jumper settings EACH TIME i wanted to get the dvd drive working again.  a different setting worked most every time

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of master / slave with SATA.  Jumpers are there normally to change the speed or other settings of the drive, and never normally need to be changed.

If you are building a new machine with a new motherboard with a modern SATA controller, you shouldn't have any issues.